# Fastest way to integrate $\frac{1}{t(t^6-1)}$

Tags: integration

My friend mentioned to me that there is a very quick way to integrate $\frac{1}{t(t^6-1)}$.

The standard method for dealing with integrals of rational functions by partial fraction decomposition is long (but doable) as there are 5 terms to integrate. After playing around for some time I still don't see the fast way of doing this integral.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Once you know the general method, you are allowed to plug it into wolfram alpha. It is quite fast.

Comment: @user1952009 You cheater xD

Comment: If you are curious even in general case there are methods faster than partial fraction decomposition, I treated one example in this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138065/solve-an-integral-int-left-fracx1-3-1x-right5-3dx/2138154#2138154. The bible for this is the book of M.Bronstein referenced in my post. But for your specific question, the answer by @SimplyBeautifulArt will be quite hard to beat.

Comment: @zwim Better yet, we could just use residues.  Then my answer is immediate to the well trained eye.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac1{t(t^6-1)}=\frac{t^6-(t^6-1)}{t(t^6-1)}=\frac{t^6}{t(t^6-1)}-\frac{t^6-1}{t(t^6-1)}=\frac{t^5}{t^6-1}-\frac1t$$

The first fraction is just a u-substitution and the second is the natural logarithm, hence

$$\int\frac1{t(t^6-1)}\ dt=\frac16\ln|t^6-1|-\ln|t|+c$$

---

For a more general method, we have PFD over the complex plane:

$$\frac1{t(t^6-1)}=\sum_\omega\frac{\operatorname{Res}(f,\omega)}{t-\omega}$$

where the sum is taken over the roots of $t(t^6-1)$.  When $\omega=0$, we have

$$\operatorname{Res}(f,0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac t{t(t^6-1)}=-1$$

When $\omega^6=1$, we have

$$\operatorname{Res}(f,\omega)=\lim_{t\to\omega}\frac{t-\omega}{t(t^6-1)}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}=\frac16$$

Thus, it becomes clear that

$$\int\frac1{t(t^6-1)}\ dt=-\ln|t|+c+\frac16\sum_{\omega^6=1}\ln|t-\omega|=\frac16\ln|t^6-1|-\ln|t|+c$$

Comment: Well darn I feel silly for not seeing this...

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou As a side note, it is possible to perform "partial" partial fraction, where we rewrite as follows:$$\frac{a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+a_{n-2}t^{n-2}+\dots+a_0}{(t-b_1)(t-b_2)\dots(t-b_n)}=\frac{P_1(x)}{t-b_1}+\frac{P_2(x)}{(t-b_2)\dots(t-b_n)}$$or arrange the factors in the denominator however we please.  Indeed, it is not necessary to fully factor the denominator to do PFD...

Comment: I've personally never seen a sum of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{\omega^6 = 1} \ln |t-\omega|$... what is the trick to quickly simplifying this without combining logs and using properties of $n$-th roots of unity?

Comment: Best way I can think of to prove this is to write as $\displaystyle\ln\left(\prod_{\omega^6=1}(t-\omega)\right)$ and note that the inside is a polynomial with exactly $6$ roots, each being a $6$-th root of unity. We know that the function $t^6-1$ fulfils this criteria, so we simply get $\ln(t^6-1)$

Comment: @BrevanEllesfen that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int{\dd t \over t\pars{t^{6} - 1}} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ =\ x^{-2}}{=}\,\,\,
2\int{x^{11} \over x^{12} - 1}\,\dd x = {1 \over 6}\,\ln\pars{x^{12} - 1} =
{1 \over 6}\,\ln\pars{{1 \over t^{6}} - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{{1 \over 6}\,\ln\pars{1 - t^{6}} - \ln\pars{t} +
\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}}}
\end{align}